# Clip text overrun from beginning Javafx

Tags: javafx

Similar to `OverrunStyle.LEADING_ELLIPSIS` I would like to shorten my word from the words start, but without the ellipses, similar to ovverun style clip. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Label.setEllipsisString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setEllipsisString-java.lang.String-):

```
Label myLabel = new Label("SomeLongText");
myLabel.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.LEADING_ELLIPSIS);
myLabel.setEllipsisString("");
```

This should only truncate the text as needed, without appending extra characters (...).

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for something for use outside of the fx label etc, StringUtils might be able to help

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#abbreviate-java.lang.String-int-

```
 StringUtils.abbreviate(null, *, *)                = null
 StringUtils.abbreviate("", 0, 4)                  = ""
 StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno", -1, 10) = "abcdefg..."
 StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno", 0, 10)  = "abcdefg..."
 StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno", 1, 10)  = "abcdefg..."
 StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno", 4, 10)  = "abcdefg..."
 StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno", 5, 10)  = "...fghi..."
 StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno", 6, 10)  = "...ghij..."
 StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno", 8, 10)  = "...ijklmno"
 StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno", 10, 10) = "...ijklmno"
 StringUtils.abbreviate("abcdefghijklmno", 12, 10) = "...ijklmno"
```